# JBOSS 7.1 war deployment issue

Tags: jboss

I am new to JBOSS Application server 7.1.

I created war for my application and put it in deployments folder.

Then I started the JBoss 7.1 application server.

War got extracted at some temporary location.

Now for my application We have some configurable properties.

From inside application these properties get modified and get saved in context/web-inf/properties folder.

This works for me when server is running.

But if I restart the server then JBOSS 7.1 again redeploys the war at some different temporary location (instead of using previous location).

Due to this my saved properties get lost.

Is there any way I can prevent this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the resources inside your war at runtime is a very bad idea.

Instead of saving this property file in `/web-inf/properties/` put it somewhere else. (for instance `$USER_HOME/.myapp/config/`)

Why is it a bad idea ?

- the problem you have is a good reason (i.e. overridden/lost on re-deploy)
- you can configure some app server so that it re-deploy the app when a resource is modified. (and so it may trigger a re-deploy unexpectedly)

Comment: Hi Ben thanks a lot for ur reply.
I know it is bad idea to update resources inside war at runtime but thats the way this war is working from long time. Right now the option that u told me is not feasible in my case. 
I dont know why JBOSS 7.1 is the only server which extract the war each time on server start (that too at a new location) I checked this on Weblogic, Tomcat and Websphere they extract war only first time and then use the same copy on each server start. Is there any way to configure JBOSS so that it will use already extracted war?

Comment: you can probably configure jboss to do that (it must be very similar to Tomcat, since the ServletContainer inside jboss is Tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying your WAR through the jboss-cli or through the admin console. It may be re-loading the item in the deployment folder every reboot since that folder is used for hot deployments.

Doing it through the two methods I mentioned may preserve the war and keep the same tmp files.

Tho ben75 is correct and you should move your property files externally.

JBoss also operates by using a Virtual File System (VFS) which I'm not sure if Weblogic, Tomcat or WebSphere utilize themselves.

Comment: Hi Welsh, Thank you for your answer. I tried deploying my war using JBOSS Admin Console. But still it is using different temp folder each time I restart the server. Ideally it should only deploy once and then use the same extraced directory. But here the thing is it is deploying war file on each server start.
Is there any way I can tell the JBOSS that it should use the same tmp folder each time so that I can get my work saved in properties files.

Comment: I don't think so, and I think that's just because of the way that JBoss is created.

Answer (score 0):

- It may work in other application servers, but I have not found that the behaviour you expect is guaranteed by the servlet specification.
- Normally data centers never accept a self-modifying application. One of the reasons is that there is normally no regular backup of extracted war files, because data is just not supposed to be there. Another reason is the need to differ between environments: Initial configuration is most often not the same, and so you have to ship it separately, because the .ear/.war file must always be identical.
- Your implementation is quite complex, if it implements cluster-wide property synchronization correctly.

So if you are not running in a cluster, just write the properties file into a defined directory outside of the application server, and make sure that there is a regular backup. This way configuration is kept, if the application is updated.

In case of a cluster persist the changes into a database, and synchronize the values using JGroups/Infinispan, for example.